# Jenkins - PmdPublisher: How to use "usePreviousBuildAsReference" from other branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pmd

We're using the PmdPublisher class in Jenkins to report PMD warnings/notices.

Using
`step([$class: 'hudson.plugins.pmd.PmdPublisher', pattern: 'reports/pmd_*.xml', usePreviousBuildAsReference: true])`

We've set up a MultiBranch pipeline, so for every new branch it creates builds. But everytime "Build 1" has the message "XXX new warnings".
And "Build 2" has (Reference build: #1).

But what I want to set up is that "Build 1" has a "Reference build" to the branch of which it was created.

Plugins used:

- Static Analysis Utilities
- PMD Plug-in